# 意味のある編集について

Tags: 討議

編集は良い質問にするために意味を明確にしたり、読みやすくする意図があると思いますが、
[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/29407/revisions)のタイトルから"。。。"を取り除く修正がありました。

確かにタイトルを読んで不要な文字ではあるのですが間違いではないですし、
個性として捉えると、あまり意味のない編集のようにも思えます。
（意味の改善でもないし、句読点を３つ削除した程度で読みやすくなるとは思えない）

[編集のガイドライン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)からすると

> 編集は実のあるものであることが期待されます。

……とあり、意味のない修正は、あまりしない方がいいかと思われます。

例えばこの修正に加えて、タグの追加などが一緒にある、
回りくどい言い方で本文が分かりづらい質問の編集などは勿論意味のある編集なのですが、
質問者の記述の仕方だけの編集は、わざわざ編集を行う必要性はないのではないでしょうか？

最近、文言の揚げ足取りのような編集もよく見るので
意味のある編集とは何か？と言うのを明確にしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

本題の、タイトルから句読点3つを削除することに意味/意義はあるのか。個性の(個人の表現の自由の)範疇ではないのかについて考えてみました。

文章におけるタイトルは、簡潔に質問の内容を表す索引のようなものなので、できる限り
* 簡潔である
* わかりやすく読みやすい
* 問題の内容が的確に表されている
であってほしい性質の文だと思っています。しかもこれは、質問一覧をみている閲覧者の目に入ってくる情報なので、これが上記の性質をなるべく満たしていることはユーザーにとっての価値に繋がると思います。

本文で、文体が多少おかしかったり、些細な文法ミスであったり、丁寧語であったりそうでなかったりは、そこは表現の自由の範疇でいいと思うので、今回の修正が本文の方なら、表現の自由の範疇で多分却下したと思います。ただ、タイトルなので、ほんの少しでも上記性質を満たせるようになるのなら、それは価値のある編集だとは思います。

編集価値が小さすぎるかどうかの判定には、別回答で述べた、レビューコストとの兼ね合いで判断しています。

---

で、ここまで書いて、改めて質問文を見返して、この編集で読みやすくなるとは思えない、と書いてあることに気がつきました。

それは、、自分の中だと、以下の観点での読みやすさは向上しているのではないか、と考えています。質問の一覧が並んでいた時に、句読点が3つ(特に意味もないのに)ならんでいるのは、他のタイトルからみて少し異様な感じを受けます。例えば、質問の最初と最後を【】でくくったりしてみると、視覚的な情報量が増えるので、その質問はより注目されるかもしれません。が、みんながみんなそれをやり始め、なるべく注目を浴びようとすると、なんだかそれは好ましくないと思います。(この場合、【などタイトルにおいて注目を引きつけるような文面も、ある種の個性(表現の自由)だと考えています)

上記の、自分が考えるタイトルが満たしてほしい性質を備えたタイトルが並んでいるなかで(特に意味もなく)異様に注目も浴びるようなフォーマットは、その一覧画面をみている読者にとっての読みにくさに繋がると思います。なので、今回の編集はその意味での読みやすさを向上させていると思い、承認しました。

Comment: なるほど、分かりやすいです。日本語自体、難しい部分もあるので`。。。`や`…`、`...`など含みを持たせて本文に記載するなども在りうることですね。

Answer (score 1):

今回の編集提案の承認者の一人です。議題の中心を答えているわけではないですが、自分の承認・却下の指針を。

何が適切な編集かを定義しきるのは若干難しいので、普段自分は次のことを考えて 承認・却下をしています。

この編集と同種の編集(の提案)が、例えば百倍の量で発生することになった時、それはこのサイトのためになっているか？です。(レビュー・承認のコストを含めて考えて)

今回のケースでは、自分の感覚では、まぁなるだろうな、だったので、承認を押したのですが、感覚であるので、議論の余地があると思ってます。