# 編集合戦になってしまった場合の対応

Tags: 討議, 編集

質問自体は削除されておりますが、
[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42565/)で3回ほど同じ編集が繰り返して行われておりました。

コミュニティによる編集自体は妥当なものだと思いますが、
編集された意図が質問者に伝わっておらず、躍起になって編集を繰り返しております。

この場合、いくら編集してもキリが無い状態になり、
質問自体を損ねてしまうことにも繋がりかねません。
(実際、編集合戦に嫌気が差した質問者によりコミュニティへの暴言として質問自体が無くなっています)

私としては良し悪し抜きにして下記が思いつきますが、
どうするのがベストだったのでしょうか？

- 最初から編集コメント及びコメントにて指摘する。
- 質問にクローズ投票する
- METAに誘導する
- HELPへのリンクを貼る
- 質問者が気づくまで編集合戦
- 質問者の意図優先で対応は不必要

Comment: 編集内容からして、「自分が感じた不快感を、もっと不快に感じられる言葉で投げ返す」ようなものだったので、「対応は不必要」はありえないだろうと思います。ただ、残された選択肢の中で「編集合戦」は最低の対応だったろうと思います。マイナス票と同じことですが、単に黙って編集を取り消されてもどの程度ご本人が気づいてくれるか(かなり気分を害しておられたようなので、ご本人に修正してもらえるまで動かすのは難しかったでしょうが)は怪しいところでしょう。わたし的には前にも言いましたが、他人の発言を編集する場合には編集者はその意図をきちんと説明すべきだろうと思います。

Comment: @OOPer 「意図をきちんと説明」というのは、編集内容の要約をする部分での説明を想定してらっしゃいますか？　それとも質問へのコメントでの説明でしょうか。（具体的な方法は重要視していらっしゃらないのでしたらすいません。）

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、編集内容の要約は初心者の方はその内容を確認することができないでしょう。コメントなど、誰にでも見える形で示すことを想定しています。単なる誤字脱字の修正以上の修正を行う場合、コメントを残すべきだとは思いませんか。修正内容によっては元発言者の意図を書き換えてしまっている可能性があります。そのような場合、「自分の意図を差し置いて、適当に答えられる内容の質問に書き換えられてしまう使えないサイト」と言う印象を持たれてしまうかもしれません。他人の発言内容を自由に編集できる権限を持った人は、最大限元発言者の意図を損ねないよう配慮すべきでしょう。

Comment: 質問が削除された理由ですが、「質問者によりコミュニティへの暴言として質問自体が無くなっています」というのはたぶん違っていて、ユーザーアカウントの削除＋マイナス票によるものだと思います。（参考: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2283/3054 ）質問者が編集合戦に嫌気が差したというのはその通りだと思いますが。

Comment: @mjy 削除が取り消されたので今は確認できませんが、私が最後に確認した際には「スパム、暴言として削除されました」(うろ覚え)でした。アカウントの削除に伴っての場合でもこのように出るんでしょうか？(ちょっと主題とズレますが…)

Comment: @Myaku 出ていたメッセージは「この質問はスパムまたは暴言としてマークされているため、表示されません」だったかも知れないですね。どのような場合に「スパムまたは暴言としてマーク」されるのかは、よく解らないです。[タイムライン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/42565/timeline)では「削除済み  Community♦  ユーザー 27837 が削除されました」となっているので、この質問の削除のトリガーがユーザーアカウントの削除だったのは間違いなさそうです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 私の理解

今回の件に関して、自分の理解していることをまとめると:

1. 質問自体それ以外の内容(以前の回答では理解できなかったこと + それに対する若干の不満)が、質問本文に含まれる形で投稿される
2. 編集により、この文言が削除される
3. これに気付いた質問者が、再度、質問自体以外の内容を編集により復活させる
4. Edit War 的になる

だと理解しています。

## 原理原則的な分析

stackoverflow は、信用度に基づいて権限が増加していくモデルを採用していますが、コミュニティである以上、メンバー同士の衝突は発生してしまうものなのかな、と思っています。

このような衝突が発生したとき、従うべきは stackoverflow の原理原則なのではないか、と思います。個人的には、これは以下だと思っています。

1. プログラマーのために、プログラミングに関する知見を Q&A で集積する
2. [Be Nice](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

コミュニティにとって新しいメンバーは、 stackoverflow のルール(プロトコル)について、熟知していることは、おそらくないと思います。特に、

1. マイナス投票や、質問編集などのモデレーションの機構は、質の高いコンテンツを維持するための仕組みであって、これらを行っている人たちに、何らそれ以外に含むことはない
2. 質問・回答投稿は、 stackoverflow の、集合知的コンテンツの核であって、次第に(モデレーションを通じて) Wikipedia のように、より多くの人をターゲットとしたような形式へと整理されていくことがある。

あたりは、これを知らずに参加しようとしてみると、ほぼ間違いなく面喰らうかもしれないなと思っています。

## 今回はどうあるべきであったか

今回の問題は、

1. 自分の投稿を編集できるという、 Original Poster の権限
2. サイトの投稿の質を向上させるさせるための、[質問と回答の編集権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

がぶつかって発生したのだと考えています。衝突していて、システム的にこれが解決できない場合、これを解消するために従うべきは Be Nice であると考えています。なので、コメント欄で OOPer さんも言及していますが、

1. Edit War の兆候が表われた時点で、 Be Nice 特に「相手の善意を前提として」、ここで述べているような理由があるので、質問投稿を編集しようと思っているないし編集してもらいたい旨を伝える。
2. 「相手の善意を前提として」行動してコミュニケーションとっていって、しかしそれでも解決できない場合は、 meta 投稿だったり通報だったりで、エスカレーションする。

がいいのではないか、と思います。

Answer (score 7):

件の質問者さんは気の毒であったと思います。
このサイトの初めての利用でマイナス票が集中する現状はおかしいです。
しかし、それと編集の可否は別の問題ですので、分けて論じるべきかと思います。

#### Q&Aに無関係な文言の削除は妥当

Metaを除くStackOverflowでの質問は「発言（意見を述べること）」とは違います。
意見を述べることは想定されておらず、ライセンスも[見解を示す作品のライセンス](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ja.html#OpinionLicenses)ではなく、[CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja)が採用されています。
他者による編集は推奨されており、その意味ではStackOverflowでの質問は、掲示板への投稿よりも、Wikiの項目作成に近いです。

> すべての貢献は、Creative Commons でライセンスされています。このサイトは、Wikipedia 同様協同で編集されます。改善が必要なものが見つかったら、編集をクリックしてください!
>
> 質問および回答が明確で趣旨に沿っており、最新の状態を保つために、編集は重要です。自分の貢献が他の信頼できるユーザーによって協同で編集されるのが嫌な場合は、このサイトは向いていないでしょう。
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Q&Aが質問者の意見を述べる場になってしまえば、技術的なQ&Aになることを期待した回答者の労力も無駄になってしまいます。

今回の例では、質問の技術的な点とは無関係な文言がQ&Aの価値を損なっていました。
技術的な質問部分を変更することなく、無関係な文言のみを削除した編集は妥当であり、行うべきであったと思います。
「当方初心者」という記述は質問に関係することとして残してもよかったかもしれませんが。

（質問者の個性・文体を抹消してしまうような編集が妥当であるかは別の議論です。
過去の議論に「[意味のある編集について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2317/3054)」や、 「[ネコ語の語尾を編集して「ですます体」にするのは問題ないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1649/3054)」があります）

#### サイトの利用に関する意見や相談はMetaに誘導する

一般に、質問者に説明が必要な点はコメントで補うことが必要で、無言のマイナス票や編集はそれの代りにはならないと思います。
今回はこの説明が足りていませんでした。
Metaに誘導するコメントが付けられてからは編集合戦は行なわれていないようですし、以前にあった別の編集合戦もコメントで説明をすることで終了しています。

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia等における「編集」はいわば「詠み人知らず」な文書に対する**共同編集**なので、編集合戦も起こりうるでしょうが、SOにおいての文書(回答や質問)は必ず**元の発言者**がいるわけで、もし第三者(=他人)が編集を行う場合には元発言者の意図を尊重しなければいけません。

極端な話、元の発言に暴言が含まれるなど問題がある場合でも、他人がむやみやたらに編集すべきでは無いと思います(まずはコメントなどで指摘を行うべき)。

件の質問について、質問主の方にはもう少し冷静さが欲しかった一方で、第三者による「ロールバック」や「編集(本文の一部を削除)」が妥当な対応だったかは疑問が残ります。

Answer (score 1):

**ユーザーの私的領域とそれに対する他者の干渉の問題**
　コミュニティによる自治社会です。私たちがルールを破ったり、あかんことをするとコミュニティ内の他のユーザーからおしかりを受けます。しかし私たちも現実社会でコミュニティに属していながら、プライバシーも認められているように、必ず私的領域も持っています。この私的領域ってどこまでなのでしょうか？
　
　１ユーザーのリアル社会を含む投稿前の状態。（パソコン前の生活）
　２ユーザーが投稿した後の質問や回答、コメントなどを含む？
　
　私たちは自分たちの作ったものに少なからず愛着を抱きます。自分の作った工作物を否定されたり、料理を拒絶されたりすると嫌ですよね。自分の作った質問や回答にも人により愛着を抱いていると思います。
　そういう時、不味い物を作るあなたが悪いとか言えますか？（無理にうまいとも言えませんから困りますよね。）
　ともかく、自分がそれだけ時間をかけたものを他人に悪く評価されるのは嫌だという気持があるもんです。
　人の心は国みたいなものです。どんな大義名分があれ、国に侵攻すると、反発を受けるのは歴史が示していますし、皆さんの人生経験からも判っていただけると思います。
　
　よくよく考えれば、その料理はその人自身ではなく、工作物もその人自身ではありません。しかし否定されると哀しいのは、その人自身の領域に属していることだからです。
　
　例えば自分の好きな俳優やタレントや映画やアニメや漫画や趣味等等、そうしたものを、他者から、どうしてそんなものが好きなのか？と言われると気分が悪くなった経験はありませんか？
　
　否定されたのは、自分ではなく、俳優やタレントや映画やアニメや漫画やその趣味それ自体で、自分自身ではありません。
　
　しかし、自分が好きなものを否定されると、その否定されたもの・ひとを好きになっている自分がおかしいと言われているようなものなのです。つながりがあるんです。絆というものでしょうか。

質問や回答も、投稿されたときには、その投稿者の表現物です。その投稿者に属するものです。
だから、同様に否定されると、その人は気分を害するんです。

勝手に他人の家に上がり込んだら嫌なように、その領域を侵さないようにしなければ喧嘩になります。
　しかしあまり相手に配慮しすぎると、全く直すべきところが直されないまま放置されてしまいます。
　コミュニティには他者の領域に関わる編集という機能がありますし、クローズ票などを入れることが出来ます。コミュニティによる是正が求められているのも確かです。
　だから相手の領域に入る事を一定の場合に許されているという事が出来ます。
　
　特に、改行や段落、文字の誤字脱字、コードの括り方等の形式的なものについては、相手にとって何が替えられたのか、どうしてかえられたのかわかりやすいから、あまり相手に配慮する必要もない気がいたします。表現内容自体に関わらないからです。
　しかし、相手の表現内容にかかわるような是正だと、相手を怒らせることがあるようです。単に形式的なものに止まらないからだと思いますし、相手の考えや思考等がかなりかかわっている場所で、表現したいもの自体であることが多いからです。
　
　だから、この部分には、極力触れるべきではないと考えます。

暴言等、他者が見れば気分を害するような表現が書いてあるときはどうするのか？

今回の件で、どのような事が書かれていたために、その表現内容が書き換えられてしまったのかは見逃してしまいました。しかし、カンカンに怒っておられたようなので、結構ここに関わってしまわれたのかなと思います。あまりにも他者を誹謗中傷するような発言ならばわかる部分もあります。
　しかしここの投稿者の方たちの反応を拝見しますと、質問者の方への一定の配慮をという方向性が見て取れますので、そこまでひどい内容ではなかったのではないかと考えます。
　
　編集者にとって、他者の投稿を編集すれば、その部分が自分の表現内容になります。それをまた直されてしまうと、あたかも編集者が、まさにその書き換えられた投稿者のように、自分の表現内容を否定されたかのように感じ、お互いに書き換え合戦が始るのだと考えます。編集者も投稿を書き換えられた人と大体似たような心境になるんですね。だからどういう気持ちなのかはわかっておられると思います。ほかの理由かもしれませんけど、私に推測できるのはこういうところです。
　
　あまりにも他ユーザーが見て気分を害するような場合であっても、相手の表現物を書き換えることになるため、相手の気分を害しやすいです。事前にせよ事後にせよ、コメントを残し、書き換えた簡単な理由などを書いて通知することは、最低限必要だったのではないかなと考えます。

それが是正されるものであることが明白なのに、どうしても意固地になっているようなら、METAで審議にかけた方がいいと思いますし、もう少し周りの意見が集まるのを待った方がいいかもしれません。ここはコミュニティなので、自分ひとりで背負うのも危険だと思います。私はマイナス票を入れられたりすると哀しいですが、コミュニティの人を結構信用しています。感情や慾にながされて投票やコメントを入れるような人はあまりいないと考えています。少なくともちゃんとした考えや意見を以て行動されていることが、コミュニティ全体からわかります。

だから、こういう感情で入れられていると思わしき事件が起こると残念です。コミュニティは互いに高め合おうとするものであって、互いに悪いと思わしきものをやっつけようという流れになるのは少し寂しい気がします。
　
　**今回の対応はどうすべきか**
相手の投稿に触れる前に、コメントを残し、編集理由を書く。あるいは投稿者に是正してほしい箇所とその理由を書く。
　あまりにも投稿者がおかしいことが明白なら、自分ひとりで行動せずコミュニティのメンバーが集まるまで待った方がいいと思います。